# RLE algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, run-length-encoding

First, english isn't my primary language. I'm new to C, and one of my tasks is doing RLE algorithm in specific case which it's count only on a conditions like those:
`'aaabb'`
`'bbbrr'`
`'ggskkkk'` and etc...
On This case: `'aaaaaayyy'`,
I've done this code:

```
void StringRLE(char *pointer)
{
    char rle[strlen(pointer)];

    int i=0;
    int rleCount =1;
    char *s = pointer+1,ch;
    while(*pointer!= '\0')
    {                     
        if(*pointer==*s)
            rleCount++;
        else
        {
            itoa(rleCount, rle, 10);
            ch = *pointer[i];                                
            strcat(rle, ch);  
            puts(rle);                                            
            rleCount = 1;   
        }

        pointer++;  
        s++;
        i++;
    }                                                                         
}
```

But when I'm using `itoa` to convert my `int` to string for the second time, when it's done counting the 'y' the `itoa` overrides the RLE string. Why, and how may I solve it?

Comment: First: `char rle[strlen(pointer)];` should be `char rle[strlen(pointer) + 1];`

Comment: Don't forget that in the worst case, the RLE string can have twice the length of the source string. Therefore, `char rle[strlen(pointer)*2 + 1];`

Comment: BTW this code doesn't compile for me. Many compilation errors - 1. When you declare rle, you can't use strlen. It should be a constant value, 2. At `ch = *pointer[i]` should be *(pointer + i) and 3. At `strcat(rle, ch)` should be `strcat(rle, &ch)`. Are you even able to reun this code. What compiler are you using.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me. Made a few changes to make it compile and run.

```
void StringRLE(char *pointer)
{
    char *rle = new char[strlen(pointer)];

    int i=0;
    int rleCount = 1;
    char *s = pointer+1, ch[2] = {0,0};
    while(*pointer!= '\0')
    {                     
        if(*pointer==*s)
            rleCount++;
        else
        {
            itoa(rleCount, rle, 10);
            ch[0] = *pointer;
            strcat(rle, ch);
            puts(rle);                                            
            rleCount = 1;   
        }

        pointer++;  
        s++;
        i++;
    }                                                                         
}
```